# How persist redux store to localstorage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

can't persist store to localstorage, using redux-persist.
Have error:

> Store does not have a valid reducer. Make sure the argument passed to
>   combineReducers is an object whose values are reducers.

Help pls to configure store or are there another ways

```
import {applyMiddleware, compose, createStore} from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import {createLogger} from "redux-logger";
import rootReducer from "../reducer/index";
import {loadState, saveState} from "../utils";
import { persistStore, persistCombineReducers } from 'redux-persist';
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';

const config = {
    key: 'root',
    storage,
}

const reducer = persistCombineReducers(config, rootReducer)


function configureStore(initialState) {
    let createStoreWithMiddleware;

const middleware = process.env.__DEV__
    ? applyMiddleware(thunk, createLogger())
    : applyMiddleware(thunk);

createStoreWithMiddleware = compose(
    middleware,
);

const store = createStoreWithMiddleware(createStore)(reducer, initialState);

let persistor = persistStore(store)

if (module.hot) {
    module.hot
        .accept('../reducer', () => {
            const nextRootReducer = require('../reducer/index');
            store.replaceReducer(nextRootReducer);
        });
}


store.subscribe(() => {
    saveState(store.getState().albums)
});

return {store, persistor};

}

export default configureStore
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I am not sure what your question is here - is this your code? what things have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please finish the tour and you will understand [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and modify question accordingly to minimal working example. Without posting your code you risk removal of your question. With your stated trail and error code... people are more willing to help you so both can learn. Question moved to editing. Reviewing finished. Enjoy SO ;-)

Comment: as Mikkel stated its not clear your question.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message is already telling - you have to pass an object to the `persistCombineReducers` method.

Please have a look at the following [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/o95yl1z6pz). (Some of your code is commented there to have a minimal example.)

So the code of your combined reducer could be like this:

```
const reducer = persistCombineReducers(config, {root: rootReducer});
const store = createStore(reducer, initialState);
```

If you're only having one reducer it would be better to use:

```
const reducer = persistReducer(config, rootReducer);
```